# An adjective for a Container that can be ordered in "Empty" state

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, adjectives, vocabulary

I have 2 types of containers, and I am looking for one (or ideally a pair of) adjective(s) that signify their differences; Here are their descriptions:

1. The first type **can be ordered as an empty container**; Later, you fill it gradually and when filled, you may consume its contents.
2. the second type, **could not be ordered in empty state**; you get it when it contains some material. later on, you may consume all of its contents, or even add extra contents to it.

They differ in the ways that you could order them, after you get them, they are basically the same.

At first, I came up with ***Decantable*** and ***UnDecantable*** adjective, but they are not very descriptive for the desired concept. Have you any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply called them ***fillable*** and ***filled***.

*Fillable* indicates that you will need to fill it (or keep it around empty, I suppose) while *filled* indicates that it comes already loaded.

Now that I think about it, ***empty*** and ***loaded*** (or *filled*) could work too.